# Why subscript not showing correctly R plot

Tags: r, plot

In the **R code below**, (seems strange to me) I'm wondering WHY the subscript in `'CT'[01]` used in the `legend()`, **ZERO** doesn't show, BUT when I use `'CT'[10]` **ZERO** correctly shows?

**Here is the R code:**

```
plot(1:10,ty="n")

## This one below, `0` doesn't show in the `CT[01]` !!!!! ##

legend("topright", legend=bquote(paste("Evidence favors A ",bold(('CT'[01]))," = ", .(round(1/Gi,3)))),
   pch = "",cex=2, bty="n", inset=c(.0,-.12))

## But this one below `0` shows correctly in the `CT[10]` Ok Ok OK ##

legend("topright", legend=bquote(paste("Evidence favors A ",bold(('CT'[10]))," = ", .(round(1/Gi,3)))),
   pch = "",cex=2, bty="n", inset=c(.0,-.12))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the WHY is as follows: The function `bold()` evaluates the expression with the subscript. Therefore it evaluates the value inside the `[]`-brackets. Default is to interpret it as a number. This makes totally sense: Think of a subscript `[i]` that is evaluated in a for loop. This will do the "right" number to every plot.

Therefore the **01** will be plotted as **1** and the **10** as **10**.

So if you wish to print out the 0 in front of the 1 use `'CT'[0][1]` or `'CT'['01']`. The first one displays two numbers 0 and 1, the second one is evaluated as character and therefore the 0 will not be omitted.